# How to open the Jquery Dialog Modal on selecting tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a small search image inside the textbox .when i get tab from textbox to search image at that point  when we press enter key we need to open the Dialog modal.How can we do that . we also need to open the dialog when we click on the search Image.This part of code we already have it .

```
$('.searchimage').bind('click',function(){
    //Open Dialog and pass the parameters 
     to that dialog that are necessary.

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.searchimage').click(function(){
    $('#mymodal').dialog('open');
});
```

This will work if the dialog is created and just not opened.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.searchimage').click(function(){
    $('#mymodal').dialog();
});
```